# Why does this Dockerfile not support arguments as a group?

Tags: dockerfile

I'm trying to write a dockerfile which calls an entrypoint. However, I'm really confused why these three things are different.

The first doesn't work:

```
ENTRYPOINT [ "python detect.py --weights /model/yolov5s.pt --source /videos --project /outputs --class 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 9 10 11 12 --save-crop --conf-thres=.7" ]
```

And the second doesn't work:

```
ENTRYPOINT [ "python", "detect.py", "--weights /model/yolov5s.pt", "--source /videos", "--project /outputs", "--class 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 9 10 11 12", "--save-crop", "--conf-thres=.7" ]
```

But the third one does:

```
ENTRYPOINT [ "python", "detect.py", "--weights","/model/yolov5s.pt", "--source","/videos","--project","/outputs","--class","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","9","10","11","12","--save-crop","--conf-thres=.7" ]
```

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/), you can see that ENTRYPOINT has two forms:

- `ENTRYPOINT ["executable", "param1", "param2"]` (the exec form)
- `ENTRYPOINT command param1 param2` (the shell form)

Either way, the arguments passed to it, need to be separated (similar to your third example).

Since your examples are using the exec form, you can see why only your third example works.

Comment: i guess - this SORT of explains it. But why aren't the spaces in #1 and #2 enough? And why doesn't #2 work, where the parameters are separated?

Comment: @aronchick - Spaces are not the same as commas, so that is why they are not enough. The syntax is very clear. If you would have used the shell form, then spaces are the proper syntax there to separate arguments. As for your second question, the difference between #2 and #3 is the --class argument. As stated above, each argument needs to be separated by a comma, so I can assume that because you bunched all of them together in #2, it does not work properly. If my answer helped you, please mark it as such so other people can find it easier.